# Avoid function argument dependent on Generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

There is a factory function that needs to be passed to another function and called from there.
The argument of the function either has a type based on generic or is not passed.
What is the correct way to describe "calculation" so that it matches the type of the argument in "generator"?

Playground:
https://tsplay.dev/WylJxm

```js
type Model = {id: number};
type Calc = Record<string, number>;
declare function calc(record: Model): Calc;

type OptFnArg<Param, Result> = Param extends void ? () => Result : (arg: Param) => Result;

const run = function <Param>(modelFactory: OptFnArg<Param, Model>) {
    const calculation = (param: Param) => calc(modelFactory(param));
    //^ How to make `calculation` acceptable for `generator`?
    //  Argument of type '(param: Param) => Calc' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptFnArg<Param, Calc>'.

    const result = generator<Param>(calculation);

    return result;
}


declare function generator<Param>(calculation: OptFnArg<Param, Calc>): ''

// valid cases:

run<void>(() => ({id: 1}));
// @ts-expect-error
run<void>((q) => ({id: 1}));

run<number>((id: number) => ({id}));
// @ts-expect-error
run<string>((id: number) => ({id}));
```

Comment: I can suppose you can't do simple cast  ?
const calculation = (param: Param) => calc(modelFactory(param)) as OptFnArg<Param, Calc>;

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER Yes, that would help in this case. I wonder if there are other ways. Anyway, thank you.